# CSS :last-child selector in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am looking to select the last `td` in each row and using this css selector right now `.table td:last-child` but it doesnt work in IE so is  there any way I can select through javascript (WITHOUT ANY FRAMEWORK) for IE? to apply CSS styles.

Comment: 1) IE sux. 2) Use jquery

Comment: Yes -- you can reimplement what every framework that supports this type of selection does to choose elements that are a last child.  It's probably not a whole lot of code to do this, but really, why?  Just choose a good framework and go with it.

Comment: Both `last-child` and `first-child` should work for IE7 and up.

Comment: In my view you shouldn't include a complete framework if all you need is a very small subset of the functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var rows = document.getElementById('tester').rows;

for(var i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++) {
    rows[ i ].lastChild.style.background = 'orange';
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/JsyYR/

---

**EDIT:** If you'll be running this in all browsers, it may be safer to do this:

```
var rows = document.getElementById('tester').rows;

for(var i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++) {
    rows[ i ].cells[ rows[ i ].cells.length - 1 ].style.background = 'orange';
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/JsyYR/2/

This is because some browsers will insert a text node if there's any space between the last `</td>` and the closing `</tr>`. As such, `lastChild` wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

To do this in JavaScript you need something like:

```
var tableRows = document.getElementById('tableid').childNodes
var tableCells = tableRows[tableRows.length - 1].childNodes;
var lastCell = tableCells[tableCells.length - 1];
```

This assumes the table is of the format  with nothing between those tags. No tbody or such.

Alternatively you could simply use `getElementByTagName('td')` and get the last element of the returned array. The downside of this is that it won't work for a page with more than one table.

Comment: Browsers typically insert a `<tbody>` if it is missing. Anyway, this would only affect the last cell of the last row.

Comment: That's why I said assuming no tbody. Anyway its not a huge leap of logic to adapt the code for a different HTML structure.

Comment: My point is that you can't assume no `<tbody>` because the browser will likely insert it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you could or not should be moot. Of course you *could* because Javascript frameworks can do this.

Whether you should spend the time reinventing the wheel when you could just add a small dependency on a JS library, should be the question.

Comment: It's also a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Not really. Valid answers do sometimes include "Don't reinvent the wheel, you're being silly."

Comment: In my views using a framework just for a selector is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, you can reference `.lastChild` on any DOM object, but you would have to get the elements first, so without jQuery or similar, it's not as easy as it sounds.

The obvious answer is "Use JQuery". You have specified against this (ie "without any framework"), but it is by far the most obvious solution.

Another solution is [Dean Edwards' IE7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) (and related IE8.js and IE9.js) which is a Javascript include that attempts to patch old versions of IE to be more compatible with standard CSS, etc. I believe it fixes `:last-child` selector. But again, it is a third-party library so you may not want to use it.

You could, of course, just add an additional class to the elements that you want the last child styles to apply to, and then just reference that in your CSS instead of last-child. Not ideal given that `last-child` is specifically aimed at avoiding you having to do that, but it does give you guaranteed compatibility.